# how to get the parameters in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to get the value of material_sort_id

```
Started GET "/materials?utf8=%E2%9C%93&material%5Bmaterial_sort_id%5D=1&material%5Bbrand_id%5D=1&commit=%E6%9F%A5%E8%AF%A2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-28 16:06:34 +0800
Processing by MaterialsController#index as HTML
        Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "material"=>{"material_sort_id"=>"1", "brand_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"查询"}
```

this is my code :

```
puts params[:material_sort_id].present?
```

I got false.  How do I get it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
params[:material][:material_sort_id]
```

You can get it like this

Answer (score 1):

According to the logs

```
"material" => {"material_sort_id"=>"1", "brand_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"查询"}
```

Your `params[:material_sort_id]` is inside the `"material"` key so you can't access directly.
It's something like you have 2 Hash the 1st Hash key contains another Hash

```
e.g { "a" => { "b"=> "1", "c" => "2" } }
```

To access you can use following.

```
params[:material][:material_sort_id]
```

To Check whether its present or not you can use following.

```
params[:material][:material_sort_id].present?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Loop 
{
    //Code   
    puts params[:material][:material_sort_id];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might possible that url is not having material hash itself. In that case you can write

```
params[:material].try(:material_sort_id)
```

In above case it will query material_sort_id on material only if material hash is not nil. If it is not nil it will return expected result else return false instead of any error